# Does anyone know how to make it so every entry has an ID one more greater than the last in SQL?

Tags: sql

[image]

How do I make it so the IDs go up by 1 every time it's been added?

Comment: This is generally accomplished with an auto-increment or sequence, but the details depend on what database you're using. Read your database docs.

Comment: Use auto increment

Comment: You're not storing passwords as freeform text are you?!?  Surely they're hashed?!?  https://www.lostmypass.com/blog/db-passwords/

Comment: Also note that since you have more than one row with the same `id`, you must not have declared that column as the primary key, which is going to lead to bad times if you're expecting it to be unique. You probably also want a unique constraint on `username`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky How do I do that

Comment: _"Read your database docs."_

Comment: @NeonBLOX - Hover your cursor over the `sql` tag on your question.  You'll see that there are many variants of `sql` each with their own syntax and functionality.  If you want answers specific to your database management system, you need to specify which one you're using.  *(Which is what that tool tip **tells** you to do.)*

Comment: @MatBailie from what i know its said MariaDB, is that what i am looking for in variants?

Comment: Okay I got to this point and the command is now this: `CREATE TABLE `id16615332_users2`.`users` ( `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `username` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL , `password` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , `registry_date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ENGINE = InnoDB;` to make the table, it errors this: `#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key` what does this mean?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The fix for this is using auto increment. The query will be a bit different depending on which database system you are using. If you are using something like MariaDB or MySQL these query's will work.

If you are creating a table this query can be used.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName(
    columnName int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    anOtherColumnName varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (columnName)
);
```

Or you can alter the table by using this SQL query.

```
alter table yourTableName modify yourColumnName int AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

If you want to learn more about auto increment visit:
https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: good you want to help, but it should be a comment